# Неправильный вывод сообщений ботом Telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['calc1'])
def text(chat_data: Message):
    bot.send_message(chat_data.chat.id, 'Вычисление N с помощью <b>Pyrocalc</b>: \nВведите в чат: «поиск n», чтобы начать', parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda chat_data: chat_data.text.lower() == 'поиск n')
def handle_search_n(chat_data: Message):
    if chat_data.text == 'поиск n' or 'Поиск n':
        bot.send_message(chat_data.chat.id, 'Пожалуйста, введите известное значение <b>i</b> в следующем сообщении.', parse_mode='html')
        Calculator.calcsave = 'поиск n'
    elif chat_data.text != 'поиск n' or 'Поиск n': 
        bot.send_message(chat_data.chat.id, f'Ошибка! \n<b>i</b> Введите указанную  в сообщении бота фразу!', parse_mode='html')
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda chat_data: Calculator.calcsave == 'поиск n')
def handle_i_value(chat_data: Message):
    try:
        i = int(chat_data.text)
        if i > 0:
            n = 2 ** i
            bot.send_message(chat_data.chat.id, f'<b>N</b> = {n}', parse_mode='html')
        else:
            bot.send_message(chat_data.chat.id, f'Ошибка! \n<b>i</b> должна быть больше нуля!')
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(chat_data.chat.id, 'Пожалуйста, введите целое число для значения <b>i</b>.', parse_mode='html')
```

После вывода значения N, бот не должен повторно отправлять сообщение с просьбой "ввести число i", а бездействовать пока команда не будет введена снова. Пытался это реализовать, но безуспешно, надеюсь на помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После вывода N условие `Calculator.calcsave == 'поиск n'` сохраняется.

Как пример можно передать значение `None`:

```
i = int(chat_data.text)
    if i > 0:
        n = 2 ** i
        Calculator.calcsave = None
        return bot.send_message(chat_data.chat.id, f'<b>N</b> = {n}', parse_mode='html')
```

И добавил `return`, что б полностью завершить функцию и вывести сообщение в качестве результата.